# Dynamically generate list from json data in react

Tags: json, reactjs, map-function, primereact

I am using `primereact` to generate table and i wanted to implement `ColToggle` Here is the `link` `https://www.primefaces.org/primereact/#/datatable/coltoggle`. Since I am dynamically generating columns from `JSON Server` , I want to dynamically generate this dropdown list for `ColToggle` implementation because i am taking api url from user input, to `populate the dropdown`:

```
let columns = [
            {field: 'vin', header: 'Vin'},
            {field: 'year', header: 'Year'},
            {field: 'brand', header: 'Brand'},
            {field: 'color', header: 'Color'}
        ];
```

and this is what i am trying to do:

```
fetch(this.state.apiURL)
            .then((response) => response.json())
            .then((findresponse) =>{
                this.setState({
                    columnSelector: findresponse.rootHeader
                });
                console.log(this.state.columnSelector);
                this.state.columnSelector.map((col) => {
                    return this.columns_multiselect = [{field: col.field, header: col.header}];
                })
                console.log(this.columns_multiselect);
            });
```

See the Map function in the code. `JSON link:` `http://myjson.com/1620im`.

This should be my output:

```
           [
                {field: 'vin', header: 'Vin'},
                {field: 'year', header: 'Year'},
                {field: 'brand', header: 'Brand'},
                {field: 'color', header: 'Color'}
            ];
```

How can i do this?

Comment: What is your error? and if you are using service then what is your response look like? Do you want to generate object from response?

Comment: See the Link above of Coltoggle, everything is written inside constructor which is hard coded. I want to dynamically generate the list  which will be populated. And i want this list to be generated by json data. Please look into json data. I have provided the link.

Comment: Sorry I am not able to open link due to restricted sites

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may be looking for this,

```
this.columns_multiselect = this.state.columnSelector.map(col => ({field: col.field, header: col.header}))
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your mapping to this

```js
this.columns_multiselect = this.state.columnSelector.map((col) => {
    return {field: col.field, header: col.header};
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You're not actually updating the state with this mapping function so react doesn't know to rerender.

*e.g.*

```
this.state.columnSelector.map((col) => {
  return this.columns_multiselect = [{field: col.field, header: col.header}];
})
```

*Instead, try this*

```
this.setState({
  columnOpts: this.state.columnSelector.map(col => ({
    label:col.header,
    value: { field:col.field, header: col.header }
    })
  )
})
...
<MultiSelect value={...} options={this.state.colOptions} .../>
```

Whenever a change is made to state, react will update the dom accordingly.

On an unrelated note, I would recommend using the `.foreach` loop instead of map if you're not returning a value. No need allocating extra memory.

Comment: that threw an error in ' : ' after value and header. ' ; ' expected

Answer (score 0):

After the answer by @Jadip, the dropdown list was populated correctly but on unchecking the columns from the dropdown list, it did not disappeared.

The issue is solved. I was not generating columns on the newly state set by dropdown list.

Previous:

```
        var columns = this.state.jsonData.rootHeader.map((col,i) => {
            return <Column key={i} field={col.field} header={col.header} sortable={this.state.isSortable} />;
        });
```

Now:

```
        var columns = this.state.cols.map((col,i) => {
            return <Column key={i} field={col.field} header={col.header} sortable={this.state.isSortable} />;
        });
```